# How do i access app variables from other modules in node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I need to access variables declared in app.js using express 2 and node 0.8; i have the following code:

```
app.js
------
[.....]
var server = app.listen(3000);
var io = require('socket.io');
io.listen(server);
exports.io=io;

module.js
----------
var app=require("./app");
console.log(app.io);
```

but app.io is undefined ... what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Where is module.js required?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add a `console.log` right next to when you set `exports.io` in `app.js`, this is likely to happen after `console.log(app.io)` runs in `module.js`.

Instead, to better control the order, you could export an init function in `module.js`, and call it from `app.js`.

module.js

```
var io = null;
exports.init = function(_io) {
  io = _io;
}
```

app.js

```
var server = app.listen(3000);
var module = require('./module')
var io = require('socket.io');
io.listen(server);
module.init(io);
```

Answer (score 3):

When you do the `require` of `module.js` make sure to pass the variable `app` to the constructor. Example.

app.js

```
var app = express();
var mod = require('module')(app);
```

module.js

```
// Module constructor
var app;
var m = module.exports = function (_app) {
    app = _app;
}

m.myFunction = function () {
    // app is usable here
    console.log(app);
}
```