# Express 4 ans Socket.io - Access app.io in modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

Im a using socket.io and Express 4 and I have problems passing the `io` to other modules.

In my **app.js**, I attach io to app like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var socket_io = require('socket.io');
var app = express();
app.io = socket_io();

module.exports = app;
```

My server is defined in./bin/www not in app.js and `io` is attached to the server like this:

**./bin/www:**

```
var app = require('../app');
var http = require('http');

server.listen(3000);
app.io.attach(server);
```

In my module I am trying to import `app` to access `app.io` but I probably have a circular dependancy problem because `app` is an empty object.

**module.js**

```
var app = require('../app');

console.log(app)
--> {}
```

I have tryed solutions suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15071123/1914034) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10090414) questions, but they are not working. I suspect the fact I am creating the server in ./bin/www might be the cause.

What can I do to access `app` in other modules?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this answer: [Using socket.io in Express 4 and express-generator's /bin/www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24609991/using-socket-io-in-express-4-and-express-generators-bin-www)

**app.js**

```
// Socket.io
var io = socket_io();
app.io = io;

var routes = require('./routes/index')(io);
```

**index.js**

```
module.exports = function(io) {
    var app = require('express');
    var router = app.Router();

    io.on('connection', function(socket) { 
        (...) 
    });

    return router;
}
```

Also try not to require `app.js` from the modules